# How to get all FeedbackMessages from components inside specific form?

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-6

Wicket 6 no longer keeps feedback messages in session. Now they are attached to components, which I think is great move but I approach an issue connected with that. I used to remove all feedback messages that were related to the specific form like this :

```
Session.get().getFeedbackMessages().clear(new ContainerFeedbackMessageFilter(panelForm));
```

Unfortunetly right now I can't clear it like this:

```
panelForm.getFeedbackMessages().clear();
```

For obvious reasons - they are attached to components inside form. 
So is there a way to get those feedback messages by only accesing (in my case) `panelForm` or my only way to go is to call `getFeedbackMessages()` on all of my components (panelForm.component1, panelForm.component2 etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use FeedbackCollector as in example:

```
new FeedbackMessagesModel(this) {    
            @Override
            protected List<FeedbackMessage> collectMessages(Component panel, IFeedbackMessageFilter filter) {
                return new FeedbackCollector(YourComponent.this.getParent()) {
                    @Override
                    protected boolean shouldRecurseInto(Component component) {
                        return true; // your citeria here
                    }
                }.setIncludeSession(false).collect(filter);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You should use FeedbackCollector. Collect the messages and mark them as rendered.

Comment: When I mark those messages as rendered what should I do with FeedbackMessagesModel? How should I pass it to let wicket know that Ive marked them as rendered?

Comment: Nothing. Wicket will ignore and discard them if they are rendered